# In almost all dictionaries the transcription of "solely" has two "L" — [ˈs ə u l l i]. Does it mean to say "solely" with one "L" is unnatural?

Tags: pronunciation

The transcription of "solely" is [ˈsəʊ**ll**i].
The fact that there are two "L" perplexes me.
Is it unnatural for you to pronounce "solely" with one "L"? (I mean: [ˈsəʊ**l**i])

---

the list of the dictionaries where the pronunciation of "solely" is [ˈsəʊlli]:
[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/solely)
[ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/solely)
[cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/solely)

---

[vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/solely) says American speakers can omit one "L":
American English - [ˈsoʊ(l)li]
British English - [ˈsəʊlli]

Comment: It's like a trampoline. The first L goes down, and the second L springs up.

Comment: As a native BrE speaker I would find it natural to pronounce both "L"s separately, albeit very close together.

Comment: They are clearly two different l's.  In **any standard variety of English** such as AmE, BrE, Aus English or New Zealand English. ˈ

Comment: As an American English speaker, I agree with vocabulary.com: I usually hear (and say) it with just one "L", especially when speaking quickly.

Comment: @GlennWillen I agree, especially about the speaking quickly part. I _can_ pronounce it with two Ls and usually do, but in everyday speech things are different. The most important thing to remember though is that our experiences as native speakers are wrong because some people on this site say so.

Answer (score 14):

In my Canadian speech, if I'm pronouncing "solely" carefully, it's something like /'soʊɫli/.

Note the first "L" is the "dark l" that comes at the end of English syllables, like "pill" and "stall", while the second is "light l" that comes at the beginning of syllables.

Even in my rapid speech I can tell the difference between the length of the "l" in "solely" and, say, the invented acronym "SOLI".

Comment: Or the plural of _solo_ as used by musicians!

Comment: Or _souly_ meaning ‘soul-ish’, for that matter. Or, to give a more realistic pair, _wholly_ and _holy_.

Comment: The main difference might be that the L in solely is laminally articulated but the L in SOLI is apical... at least that's my tendency. I can't hear the difference in length in fast speech

Answer (score 6):

It may be prounounced as a geminate consonant, held slightly longer than a single consonant.  But this is a very subtle effect, and only perceptible in slow or deliberate speech.  In normal speech it would be hard to perceive the gemmination of the /l/

Some languages, such as Italian, have quite distinctive geminate consonants (eg *fato* v. *fatto*)  In English, it is much more subtle. And at normal speed there is probably no difference between a single and a doubled /l/.

Comment: Can’t say I agree with this. The /ll/ here is very clearly and unambiguously longer than a single /l/. Even in casual speech, I would never pronounce _wholly_ and _holy_ the same either, any more than I would pronounce _and new_ the same as _anew_. English doesn’t distinguish consonant length like Italian does, but it **does** consistently distinguish between single and doubled consonants across morpheme boundaries.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree and I am surprised you let that photography question in ELU present a confusing picture of morphemes. Anyway, it's funny but to properly say "solely", it comes very close to the doubling of a consonant in Italian.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'd pronounce *wholly* and *holy* the same for the sake of puns, but not otherwise.  So while it's unusual I wouldn't say it's unacceptable to do so.

Comment: My accent, being an Estuary-influenced London English, also has the WHOLLY-HOLY diphthong split. The difference in vowels would be much more salient than any gemination of the /l/ or mixing of dark and clear /l/ allophones in my case.

Comment: @Janus For me, at least, it's not that wholly or solely is short, so much as it is that holy and soli often also have an /l/ at the end of the syllable and the beginning of the next syllable. I don't pronounce holy as /ho li/, but /hol li/.

Comment: @trlkly That sounds exactly backwards. The longer consonant is due to the fact that the first syllable in _wholly_ ends in /l/ and the second begins in /l/; in _holy_, the first syllable has no /l/. If you’re pronouncing _holy_ as /hoʊl.li/ and _wholly_ as /hoʊ.li/, then that’s _very_ idiosyncratic – the norm is the other way around.

Comment: @Janus I'm saying I pronounce both words as [hoʊɫ.li]. When enunciating clearly, I do wind up holding the [ɫ] out longer for "wholly", but I don't always do that. So both "holy" and "wholly" can sound the same for me. But I do not pronounce it /hoʊ.li/.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose there was a geologist named Ms Hall, and they had a mineral named after them. It would be natural for it to be named **Hallite**. Think about how you would pronounce that.

Contrastingly, consider the first room you go into in a residential house. Some people call this room a hall. Suppose it has a light in it. That's the **hall light**.

Compare the pronunciations: **Hallite** vs **hall light**. ***Solely*** has the second, [geminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination), consonant in it.

For me personally, unless excused by very rapid speech, for 'solely' to be pronounced without this geminate consonant would [marked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markedness)*.

<sub>* the linguists call it that to avoid saying 'wrong' :)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It's not really strange if you disect the word.

- Sole - `səʊl`
- ly - `li`
- Solely - `səʊlli`

Because you don't pronounce the e at the end of 'sole', you end up with a double l.